# Is there a way to change test name and suite name in ReportNG report with out using testng.xml?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, testng, reportng

I am using **ReportNG** to generate the reports for test cases executed by **TestNG**.But currently I am able to change the report title only.The suite name and Test name in report is "**Command Line Suite**" and "**Command line test**" respectively.Can you help me in changing that?

I am able to change it using testng.xml but thats not something I want to do.I have configured my test cases execution using maven surefire plugin only using complex regular expressions based on naming conventions of test cases and we have a huge dependency on it.